# httpからhttpsへのリダイレクトした際、クエリが2重になってしまう。

Tags: php, wordpress

kusanagiを利用してワードプレスのサイトを作成しました。
元々運用しているサイトをワードプレスに変更したのですが、以前のサイトが、phpのクエリを持つサイトで、今回ワードプレスで静的なURLに変更しました。
top.phpなどクエリがないものについては、正常に/top/にリダイレクト出来るのですが、クエリ付きのものは、plant.php?oyasai_id=1の場合、plant.php?oyasai_id=1?oyasai_id=1と二重になってしまいます。
当初、httpsのサーバー側にplant.phpを作り、GETしてパラメータの値を見てlocationでリダイレクト設定しました。

```
if( $_GET ["oyasai_id"] == "1")  {
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
header('Location: https://example.com/oyasai/ninjin/', true, 301 );
exit();
}
elseif( $_GET ["oyasai_id"] == "2")  {
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
header('Location: https://example.com/oyasai/tamanegi/', true, 301 );
exit();
}
```

https付きでplant.php?oyasai_id=1にアクセスした場合は、指定したページに正常にリダイレクトされます。

```
https://example.com/plant.php?oyasai_id=1
↓リダイレクト
https://example.com/oyasai/ninjin/
```

http付きでのアクセスの場合のみクエリが二重になります。

```
http://example.com/plant.php?oyasai_id=1
↓リダイレクト
https://example.com/plant.php?oyasai_id=1?oyasai_id=1
```

上手く動かないので現在はplant.phpについてはリダイレクトをかけていません。
plant.phpのあるなしに関わらず、クエリが2重になるので、kusanagiの方で、httpからhttpsへのリダイレクトを行っている部分で上記のような現状が起こっているのだと思います。
出来ればクエリが2重にならず、リダイレクトしたいのです。
何卒よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

自己解決しました。
preg_matchで正常にリダイレクト出来ました。